# My application is closing android between versions 4.1 and 4.4 ionic

Tags: java, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

My application is closing on some devices with android between versions 4.1 and 4.4 already below is an error log does anyone know how to fix this problem without having to use crosswalk, for I would not leave my app with 50mb.

```
05-31 05:27:24.519 2353 2462 V AlarmManager: waitForAlarm result :8
05-31 05:27:24.529 1897 1897 I SurfaceFlinger: Device Built-in Screen -> ls 0 
05-31 05:27:24.529 1897 1897 I SurfaceFlinger: Device ScreenRecorder -> ls 0 
05-31 05:27:24.549 1897 1897 I SurfaceFlinger: Device Built-in Screen -> ls 0 
05-31 05:27:24.549 1897 1897 I SurfaceFlinger: Device ScreenRecorder -> ls 0 
05-31 05:27:24.559 1897 1897 I SurfaceFlinger: Device Built-in Screen -> ls 0 
05-31 05:27:24.559 1897 1897 I SurfaceFlinger: Device ScreenRecorder -> ls 0 
05-31 05:27:24.599 1897 1897 I SurfaceFlinger: Device Built-in Screen -> ls 0 
05-31 05:27:24.599 1897 1897 I SurfaceFlinger: Device ScreenRecorder -> ls 0 
05-31 05:27:24.609 1897 1897 I SurfaceFlinger: Device Built-in Screen -> ls 0 
05-31 05:27:24.609 1897 1897 I SurfaceFlinger: Device ScreenRecorder -> ls 0 
05-31 05:27:24.629 1897 1897 I SurfaceFlinger: Device Built-in Screen -> ls 0 
05-31 05:27:24.629 1897 1897 I SurfaceFlinger: Device ScreenRecorder -> ls 0 
05-31 05:27:24.639 4349 4349 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-31 05:27:24.639 4349 4349 W dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x433101a0)
05-31 05:27:24.649 1897 1897 I SurfaceFlinger: Device Built-in Screen -> ls 0 
05-31 05:27:24.649 1897 1897 I SurfaceFlinger: Device ScreenRecorder -> ls 0 
05-31 05:27:24.659 4349 4349 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 05:27:24.659 4349 4349 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myesporte, PID: 4349
05-31 05:27:24.659 4349 4349 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.robotium.solo.RobotiumWebClient cannot be cast to org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebChromeClient
05-31 05:27:24.659 4349 4349 E AndroidRuntime: at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebView.setWebChromeClient(SystemWebView.java:76)
05-31 05:27:24.659 4349 4349 E AndroidRuntime: at com.robotium.solo.RobotiumWebClient$1.run(RobotiumWebClient.java:59)
05-31 05:27:24.659 4349 4349 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.Instrumentation$SyncRunnable.run(Instrumentation.java:1747)
05-31 05:27:24.659 4349 4349 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-31 05:27:24.659 4349 4349 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-31 05:27:24.659 4349 4349 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
05-31 05:27:24.659 4349 4349 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
05-31 05:27:24.659 4349 4349 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 05:27:24.659 4349 4349 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-31 05:27:24.659 4349 4349 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
05-31 05:27:24.659 4349 4349 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
05-31 05:27:24.659 4349 4349 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 05:27:24.679 2353 2782 W ActivityManager: Error in app com.myesporte running instrumentation ComponentInfo{testdroid.appcrawler.testcrawler/testdroid.appcrawler.testcrawler.AppCrawlerRunner}:
05-31 05:27:24.679 2353 2782 W ActivityManager: java.lang.ClassCastException
05-31 05:27:24.679 2353 2782 W ActivityManager: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.robotium.solo.RobotiumWebClient cannot be cast to org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebChromeClient
05-31 05:27:24.689 4304 4304 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-31 05:27:24.699 4304 4319 D dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 120K, 16% free 758K/900K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 2ms
05-31 05:27:24.819 2353 2462 V AlarmManager: waitForAlarm result :8
05-31 05:27:24.929 2353 2782 I ActivityManager: Killing 4349:com.myesporte/u0a3097 (adj 0): stop com.myesporte
05-31 05:27:24.939 2353 2782 W ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{2240c9a8 u0 com.myesporte/.MainActivity t18}: app died, no saved state
```

Answer (score 0):

Some where in your code you are casting

```
RobotiumWebClient to SystemWebChromeClient
```